# Angular - ng-change not firing upon select change

Tags: angularjs

[Please see this relevant jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/509/)

Within the code I am trying to fire a method when a different option is selected to alert the user. However no event is being trigged

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller = "MyCtrl"> 
<p>Term</p>
  <select id = "term" ng-change="test()">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
  </select>       

</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('HelloApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope','$element', function($scope, $element) {

    $scope.test = function () {
     alert ("changed!");   
    }


}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some issues.

Firstly: `<div ng-controller = "MyCtrl">`  - you have spaces in between.

Secondly, you're not declaring your app with `ng-app`. **This is because you set your fiddle as jquery, and not Angular.** If you had set it as angular you wouldn't need this in the fiddle

This is your fiddle setup

[image: This is your fiddle setup]

This is an Angular fiddle setup

[image: This is an Angular fiddle setup]

Thirdly, to use `select` with AngularJS, you need to have an `ng-model` on the `select` tag. In this case i just used `bob`

```
<div ng-app="HelloApp"> <!-- declare your angular app. typically would go on body or html -->
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl"> 
        <p>Term</p>
                    <select ng-model="bob" ng-change="test()">
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                    </select>       
    </div>
</div>



var app = angular.module('HelloApp', []);  
app.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope','$element', function($scope, $element) {
console.log('ctrl working');
    $scope.test = function () {
     alert ("changed!");   
    }    
}]);
```

Here is a working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ctbLparv/

Also, if your intention is to just set a property based on the selection, you don't need to use `ng-change`. You can rely on the two-way binding.

So for example, this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ps8jnyL8/

No select is being called. We also default the selected term to 10 when it first loads.

```
<div ng-app="HelloApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl"> 
    <p>Term</p>
        <select ng-init="selectedTerm = '10'" ng-model="selectedTerm">
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
        </select>   
        <p>Selected Term: {{selectedTerm}}</p>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the working JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/G8S32/1162/

The main change was adding this line:

```
ng-model="items"
```

which doesn't do anything except update the model and cause the event to fire.

Check out the documentation for ng-change:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Particularly this line:

> The ngChange expression is only evaluated when a change in the input
>   value causes a new value to be committed to the model.

Comment: Don't need to actually use `ng-options`. They can be hardcoded as in the OP's post.

Comment: If he adds `ng-model` to his own fiddle it still won't work as he set his fiddle up with jquery, and angular as an afterthought. Where you have yours as angular, so you don't need the ng-app. he would still need that :)

Comment: I provided the working JSFiddle which addresses the conceptual issue, not the environment/syntax issues in OP's fiddle.

Comment: I get that, and that's great. Just won't help him if he tries adding just that to his own fiddle is all :)